# Multiple controls using the same javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I have a jquery calendar wherein there are js files stored in Calendar folder.When i select the date, the date is inserted into a textbox.It is working fine.But i have another textbox and i want to use the same script and function for that box too.I am new to jquery so help me out with this one.
Here is the scripting :

```
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="Calendar/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="Calendar/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="Calendar/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script>
     $(function () {
         $("#datepicker").datepicker();
     });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <tr>
  <td class="unmaintable1">Registeration starts : </td>
  <td class="unmaintable2"><input type="text" id="datepicker"/></td>
  <td class="unmaintable3">Registeration ends : 
  <input type="text" id="datepicker0"/></td>
  <td class="unmaintable4">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
```

I know this has something to do with the id but i am not sure how to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: So use a common class name

Comment: you can use css class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of id you can use css class Try this code

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="Calendar/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="Calendar/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="Calendar/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script>
     $(function () {
         $(".datepicker").datepicker();
     });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <tr>
  <td class="unmaintable1">Registeration starts : </td>
  <td class="unmaintable2"><input type="text" class="datepicker" id="datepicker"/></td>
  <td class="unmaintable3">Registeration ends : 
  <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="datepicker0"/></td>
  <td class="unmaintable4">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Yes.that worked and is far more useful than just using IDs.Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#datepicker, #datepicker0").datepicker();
```

Or you could give both elements the same class name and use that:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="datepicker"/>
<input type="text" id="datepicker0" class="datepicker"/>

$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign same css class to both these textboxes and call attach datepicker by using [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/). Example:

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="Calendar/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="Calendar/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="Calendar/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script>
     $(function () {
         $(".date-picker").datepicker();
     });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <tr>
  <td class="unmaintable1">Registeration starts : </td>
  <td class="unmaintable2"><input class="date-picker" type="text" id="datepicker"/></td>
  <td class="unmaintable3">Registeration ends : 
  <input class="date-picker" type="text" id="datepicker0"/></td>
  <td class="unmaintable4">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like if you don't want to use same class for all

```
 $("input[id^=datepicker]").datepicker();
```

Or

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"/>
<input type="text" id="datepicker0" name="datepicker0"/>

$(function() {
  $("input[name^=datepicker]").datepicker();
});
```